# json query on another page

Tags: jquery, json

I am writing a simple JSON / HTML / JQuery Mobile App.

My main page (index.html) has this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
            var url="http://localhost/json/jsondata.aspx?Option=GetTodaysEvents";
            $.getJSON(url,function(json){
                //loop through events
                $.each(json.Events,function(i,dat){
                    $("#todaycal").append("<li>"+dat.Date+"  "+dat.Title+"</li>");
                 });
                 $("#todaycal").listview('refresh');
            });
         });
    </script>
```

and it populates in:

```
<ul id="todaycal" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li data-role="list-divider">Today's Events</li></ul>
```

This works correctly.

But if I navigate to calendar.html

And run the same exact code, the listview doesn't populate. I've tried changing the pageinit to pagebefore show. I've changed the #index to #calendar, I've changed the listview id, etc..

Am I doing this right or should I be using different code on subsequent pages? The "live" page view in DW shows the query. But when I package in phonegap, I get a UL header, but not data elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: is that JS code present on both pages? if you open calendar.html on its own, does it work there?

Comment: Yes it does, but only on the PC. If I package, install, and load the app on my phone, the first page works, and not the 2nd.

Comment: When you package it in phone gap is your url still pointing to localhost ? As im gusing that json is being generated by a service on your local machine

Comment: I just changed the URL in the post for confidentiality sake. It's pointed to an accessible server.